# Variable assignment with substitution

Tags: makefile

This won't work for me. I want to make some substitution and assign it to a variable in Makefile. An example is as follows but I prefer to do it with Perl since other substitutions can be more complex than this.

```
eval.%:
    # make eval.exp-1.ans
    # $* --> exp-1.ans
    folder=`echo $* | sed -e 's/\..*//g'`
    # OR
    folder=`echo $* | perl -ne 'm/(.*)\.ans/; print $$1'
    # I want that folder will be exp-1
    echo $$folder ${folder}
```

Why this does not work? How can I do this kind of things in Makefile?

Comment: Yes, `$*` is `exp-1.ans`. `$(basename $*)` is `exp-1`.

Comment: Could you provide some examples then please?

Comment: @bobbogo hi. first, how `basename exp-1.ans` gives me `exp-1`? basename  removes the directory paths and give the base filename. For example: `basename /etc/parr.txt` gives you `parr.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  Are you trying to set a variable in your makefile, so that other recipes, etc. can see it?  Or are you just trying to set a variable in one part of your recipe that can be used in other parts of the same recipe?

Make runs recipes in shells that it invokes.  It's a fundamental feature of UNIX that no child process can modify the memory/environment/working directory/etc. of its parent process.  So no variable that you assign in a recipe (subshell) of a makefile can ever set a make environment variable.  There are ways to do this, but not from within a recipe.  However that doesn't appear (from your example) to be what you want to do.

The next thing to note is that make runs each logical line of the recipe in a different shell.  So shell variables set in one logical line will be lost when that shell exits, and the next logical line cannot see that value.  The solution is to ensure that all the lines of your recipe that need access to the variable are on the same logical line, so they'll be sent to the same shell script, like this:

```
eval.%:
        folder=`echo $* | perl -ne 'm/(.*)\.ans/; print $$1' || exit 1 ; \
        echo $$folder
```

Comment: Of course as @bobbogo points out if you're just trying to remove a suffix then a builtin function will do it.  Even more complicated substitutions can be performed by other shell functions so maybe that's all you need (note these are features of GNU make: they are not portable to other versions of make).  But you said "other substitutions can be more complex" generically, so this will help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `$(VARIABLE:suffix=replacement)` syntax? In your case, `$(*:.ans=)`. That will work for any suffix, even if it doesn't start with a dot.